Is anyone using TDRSS for tracking data?
The Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System (TDRSS), as the name suggests, is a space-based relay system for S-band data from other satellites or spacecraft. However, the "Tracking" in the name, and this question, suggest that it is also available as a form of space-based ranging data.
Are there any modern missions using TDRSS (or other space-based networks) for actual ranging and tracking data? How does that data compare to ground-based observations?

To head off the obvious comments: telemetered gps (globally, gnss) data is the go-to for data on vehicle locations, but ground-based ranging data is often still collected and processed as a backup or supplement to that gps data.
